# adjust distance between the rows and repeat header in each page?

Tags: tables, longtable

I faced problem in `longtable`, as each column is long it print in one page as picture shows, also when goes to next page need first row header repeats.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcommand{\first}{\setcounter{temp}{1}\thetemp- }
\newcommand{\following}{\stepcounter{temp}\par\thetemp- }

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks}
        \begin{longtable}{|p{1.8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.1cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Wormhole types} & \textbf{Encapsulation} & \textbf{Out of Band} & \textbf{High Power} & \textbf{Packet Relay} & \textbf{Protocol Deviations} \\\hline      
            Advantages  
            & \first there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes.
                \following RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops. 
            & \first Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops 
            & \first Control packets arrive faster
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops    
            & \first Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility.
                \following Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops   
            & control packet arrives faster \\\hline  
            Advantages  
            & \first there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes.
            \following RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops. 
            & \first Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes
            \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
            \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops 
            & \first Control packets arrive faster
            \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
            \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops    
            & \first Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility.
            \following Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops   
            & control packet arrives faster \\\hline   

        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For repeating headings, use `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`. To increase the gape between rows, you may use `makecell` and its `\setcellgaps` and `\makegapedcells` inside a group.  You won't need `center` environment as `longtale` is centered by default. BTW your table won't fit within the width (and I didn't correct it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcommand{\first}{\setcounter{temp}{1}\thetemp- }
\newcommand{\following}{\stepcounter{temp}\par\thetemp- }
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}


\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
%    \begin{center}  longtable is centered by default
        %\captionof{table}{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks}
{\makegapedcells        \begin{longtable}{|p{1.8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.1cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|}
           \caption{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks}\\ \hline
            \textbf{Wormhole types} & \textbf{Encapsulation} & \textbf{Out of Band} & \textbf{High Power} & \textbf{Packet Relay} & \textbf{Protocol Deviations} \\\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\textbf{Wormhole types} & \textbf{Encapsulation} & \textbf{Out of Band} & \textbf{High Power} & \textbf{Packet Relay} & \textbf{Protocol Deviations} \\\hline
\endhead
            Advantages
            & \first there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes.
                \following RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops.
            & \first Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops
            & \first Control packets arrive faster
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops
            & \first Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility.
                \following Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops
            & control packet arrives faster \\\hline
            Advantages
            & \first there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes.
            \following RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops.
            & \first Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes
            \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
            \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops
            & \first Control packets arrive faster
            \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
            \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops
            & \first Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility.
            \following Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops
            & control packet arrives faster \\\hline

        \end{longtable}
}
%    \end{center}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```